# Openstack router interfaces always down

Tags: openstack, conjure-up

I have an all in one openstack installation using conjure-up on a single machine.

Ive configured a network to connect my instance to the outside world, so that I can ping and ssh to it. There are 3 components to this network, a private network, a router and an external network.

The external network is a FLAT type network with its  physical network name as defined in the /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini (which is eth0) in the neutron-api/0 node.

We have a pool of IP addresses which are unused and available 10.xx.xx.70 - 10.xx.xx.74 , so the instance gets its external floating ip from this.

The instance is up and running and we can ssh into it from the compute node(nova-compute/0) but cant ping/ssh from the instance to the outside and vice-versa.

**The router has two interfaces one for the private network and the other for the external network, the status of these interfaces are DOWN**.

Restarted the l3 agent service and neutron service

> systemctl restart neutron-server.service
>
> systemctl restart neutron-l3-agent.service

but no luck. This setup is just to demonstrate a Proof Of Concept to show that a virtual machine on the cloud can be accessed from outside.

I'm mostly a novice when it comes to networking, so I may have missed some additional configurations.

I've seen this question: https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/109367/how-to-debug-the-routers-interface-all-the-interfaces-status-are-down/

and tried to make the changes and restart the services but didnt work.

Also, **openstack-config --set** commands dont work , I do have the openstack cli installed but it says command not found. If we edit the file manually it **says local changes may be overwritten**, so how can one change the config in the ml2_conf.ini ?

The server on which openstack is deployed is a Ubuntu 16.03 LTS Server. We've used lxd as a container , the name of the bridge is **lxdbr0**.